# How to copy values from one array into another within structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, copy

I'm attempting to create a new array that copies all of the values of the old array with the addition of one new value. The original array cannot be changed. These arrays are stored within structs as follows.

```
typedef float Elem;

typedef struct Vector {
    unsigned int size = 0;
    Elem arrayOfElem[];
}VECTOR;


// extend_vec
// Takes in one vector, creates a new vector, copies all of the values and adds one new value
// Original vector unchanged, returns a reference to a new vector
// In:
// Vector array of x elements
// Out:
// Vector array of x + 1 elements
// Return: 
// A pointer to the new vector

Vector *extend_vec(Vector *numbers, float element) {
    Vector *bigger = new Vector;
    bigger->size = numbers->size + 1; // set the size of the new vector to the size of the old plus one more element
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < bigger->size) {
        bigger->arrayOfElem[i] = numbers->arrayOfElem[i]; // step through the vectors and copy the values
        i++;
    }
    bigger->arrayOfElem[bigger->size - 1] = element; // set last place in the new vector to the new element
    return bigger;
}
```

I am calling the function as follows

```
// Testing for *extend_vec
       Vector big = *extend_vec(&test, 4.4);
        print_vec(&test);
        printf("\n");
        print_vec(&big);
```

"test" is my original hard coded array, and big should be the new array, and the output I am being given is

```
1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

So the function is adding one to the size of the array as I want it to but it's not copying any of the values over, and its not adding the new value to spot it just created.

My question is how should I be structuring this to make those values copy into the other array? I'm sure it's something trivial with my while loop.

Comment: You access `numbers->arrayOfElem[numbers->size]`. That's most likely a buffer overrun.

Comment: You have a variable-length structure. You can't just create it with `new Vector` - that doesn't allocate space for the array. You need something like `Vector *bigger = (Vector*)new char[sizeof(Vector) + (numbers->size + 1) * sizeof(element));`

Comment: `Vector big = *extend_vec(&test, 4.4);` This only copies `size`, and leaks all memory allocated by `extend_vec`. Make it `Vector* big = extend_vec(&test, 4.4); print_vec(big);`

Comment: Igor's solution has partially worked, but it seems like my code is altering the input "test" to where after running  extend it containts 1.1 0.0 0.0 instead of 1.1 2.2 3.3

Comment: That's most likely because `test` itself isn't correctly allocated in the first place. Is there a reason you don't just use `std::vector<float>` and be done with it?